# Data inserting sql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

> The connection must be valid and open

This error appears when the following code is executed.

```
conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=woodward1892; database=matchinfo"
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        Dim d As Integer = 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To lstT2players.Items.Count - 1
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("Insert Into batsman2(`ID`, `PlayerName`) Values('" & d & "','" & lstT2players.Items.Item(j) & ")")
            d = d + 1
        Next
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you build the MySqlCommand you should use the overload that takes the MySqlConnection otherwise the command doesn't know on which database to work with. After that the ExecuteNOnQuery should be inside the For Loop otherwise you run only the last command. Finally use parameters and not a string concatenation

```
Using conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password=woodward1892; database=matchinfo")
Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
    conn.Open()
    string cmdText = @"Insert Into batsman2(`ID`, `PlayerName`) 
                       Values(@id, @name)"
    cmd.CommandText = cmdText
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarWChar)
    Dim d As Integer = 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To lstT2players.Items.Count - 1
       cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = d 
       cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = lstT2players.Items.Item(j).ToString()
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       d = d + 1
    Next
End Using
End Using
```